# How to 'upgrade' to Windows 10, on Virtual Machine

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, upgrade

I have Windows 7 on a virtual machine on my 2015 MBP. I want to try it on boot camp and upgrade to Windows 10, but Bootcamp won't allow anything below Windows 8. So it's not possible to 'upgrade'? Do I need to buy a new licence for Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

Look, boot camp **did** allow Windows 7. It is just that it only allows 64bit.

Here is how to upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10: [Use Windows 10 on your Mac with Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990).

Also, Virtual machine is like a computer!! Just follow the following guidelines: [Upgrade to Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-upgrade).